# Get days between two dates?

Tags: java, date

I am trying to get the days between two values.  Which is in the format of MMdd.

**Ex:**
First Date = 0501 
Second Date = 0519

Trying to find the value of days between the two dates.  In this example would be 18.  Please help me with this.  I tried searching around and can't find a solution. Thank you!

**My Code**
This is what I have so far:
Getting an error: *Method days in class Project3 cannot be applied to the given type.*

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String name = input.next() + input.nextLine();
        String car = input.next() + input.nextLine();
        String key = input.next();
        String firstDate = input.next(), lastDate = input.next();

        double S = 1.0, C = 1.2, U = 1.4, T = 1.6, B = 2.0;
        final double N = 89.22, V = (N - 11.4);
        double daily, total;
        String daysBetween = Project3.days();
    }

    public static long days(Date firstDate, Date lastDate) {
        Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
        start.setTime(firstDate);
        Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
        long daysBetween = 0;
        while (start.before(end)) {
            start.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            daysBetween++;
        }
        return daysBetween;
    }
}
```

Comment: Joda-Time is what you want

Comment: Or Java 8 new Date and Time API.

Comment: What do you mean by "Scanner value"?

Comment: Unfortunately I have to get this done using the Java Library.

Comment: Check out: [`daysBetween()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html)`#daysBetween(org.joda.time.ReadableInstant, org.joda.time.ReadableInstant)`

Comment: By Scanner value I mean a Scanner utility.  That a user will type in a date in the format MMdd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a method for calculating the number of days between two dates. It keeps rolling the day forward, while the start date is before the end date. It works regardless of differences in time due to daylight saving time.

```
public static long days(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
    start.setTime(startDate);
    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
    long daysBetween = 0;
    while(start.before(end)) {
        start.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        daysBetween++;
    }
    return daysBetween;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I posted my code with this solution.  I am getting an error with the type. What have I done wrong?

Comment: If you are passing Strings, you will need to parse those to get the Date object first. You can use the simpledateformat for that:)

Answer (score 3):

Using [Joda Time `Days`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html):

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMdd");
LocalDate day1 = dtf.parseLocalDate("0501");     
LocalDate day2 = dtf.parseLocalDate("0519"); 
int daysBetween = Days.daysBetween(day1, day2).getDays();
```

Comment: Thank you! I am only to use anything in the original SDK.

Comment: He said he must use Java library.

Comment: Why downvote? There is nothing wrong in this answer. Do not accept it, but leave this answer for other people who you like to do the same.

Comment: The reason why is because I am working on a project and I can't assume that my professor has the API.  Also this inquiry is only a small part of the project.  I am stumbled on it and just needed help.

Comment: @Rafael You should start by checking with your professor. If this is a coding exercise where you have to do all the date arithmetic yourself, then that's one thing, but if it's part of a larger project, then your professor really shouldn't complain if you use a well established library like Joda. As Jean says, you use the right tools to get the job done.

Comment: @Rafael Java 8 has a new, inbuilt Time API based on JodaTime

Answer (score 2):

Joda time is the right way to do this, but if you really *have* to do it with pure JDK stuff, you can calculate it yourself.

A `Calendar` instance has a `.getTimeInMillis()` method that tells you the number of milliseconds since some fixed start point. You can take two dates, put them into `Calendar` instances, and then calculate the difference between the two `getTimeInMillis()` values.

Then divide by 1000 to get seconds; by 60 to get minutes; by 60 to get hours; by 24 to get days. And cross your fingers and hope for the best with regard to daylight saving time.

You have one other issue to get round, which is that since you've only got a day and a month, but not a year, there isn't a unique answer. The difference in days between 28 Feb and 1 Mar is one day in most years, but two days in a leap year. If you want to assume Feb has only 28 days, just choose any non-leap year you like (e.g., 2014).

Comment: @AlvinBunk What I gave him **is** using the Java library only.

Comment: Ah okay @chiastic-security I will look into this kind of solution.  Actually, I forgot to mention that my professor said it is okay to assume that February is 28 days.

Comment: @Rafael It might be, in that case, that your professor wants you to do the calculation yourself, starting from an array of month lengths. That would make for a reasonable coding exercise. If that's right, then you should probably not even be using `Calendar`. But you'll need to clarify the question with him first.

Comment: You should be careful doing calculations on `.getTimeInMillis()`. Due to day light saving time/ summer time, and other anomalies, you can get incorrect result. Ideally, you would set the time in the `Calendar` object, and roll the date a day at a time while keeping track of the number of days that have passed.

Comment: @PeterK Yes, this is really just a reasonable approximation if Joda is banned. Since OP has already assumed only 28 days in Feb, daylight saving is a relatively minor consideration :)

Comment: Calculating the difference in time by subtracting two milliseconds is erroneous at best as it does not take into account all the querks of date/time (leap years/seconds, century/millennium boundaries)